# dateTimePicker events not firing

Tags: vb.net, winforms

winForm has a TabControl with 3 tabPages. There are also 3 non-overlapping panels outside of the tabControl and tabPages in designer.

Each of the 3 tabPages contains various controls, including a DateTimePicker.

At runtime:

1. panels are resized to all be the same extent/location
2. all controls are moved from tabPage to the respective panel
3. tabControl.dispose()
4. user control panel buttons show/hide the 3 panels
5. Everything works, the datagridview and button events fire as expected.

But, the dateTimePicker.valueChangd or dateTimePicker.closeUp do not fire.

The below button.click fires as it should, but the datetimepicker doesn't, they are both created the exact same way in designer.

Any ideas?

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
    msgbox("val changed")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    refreshTable()
End Sub
```

here are how the controls are moved onLoad:

```
'change size and location of hidden panels (modules) on load
    userPanel.Size = TabControl1.Size
    userPanel.Location = TabControl1.Location

    ongoingPanel.Size = TabControl1.Size
    ongoingPanel.Location = TabControl1.Location

    archivePanel.Size = TabControl1.Size
    archivePanel.Location = TabControl1.Location

    'key=>value that will hold control=>panel string
    Dim ctrlArr As New Dictionary(Of Object, String)

    'loop over tabPages and add child controls to array as key with panel they belong to as value
    For Each tp As TabPage In TabControl1.TabPages
        For Each ctrl As Control In tp.Controls
            If tp.Name = "TabPage1" Then
                ctrlArr.Add(ctrl, "archivePanel")
            ElseIf tp.Name = "TabPage2" Then
                ctrlArr.Add(ctrl, "ongoingPanel")
            ElseIf tp.Name = "TabPage3" Then
                ctrlArr.Add(ctrl, "userPanel")
            End If
        Next
    Next

    For Each ct As Control In ctrlArr.Keys
        Dim panel As Panel = CType(Me.Controls(ctrlArr.Item(ct)), Panel)
        'move the control to paired panel
        ct.Parent = panel
    Next

    'destroy tabs, they are only for design
    TabControl1.Dispose()
```

Comment: How are the controls moved?

Comment: added code that moves controls to post

Comment: using tabcontrol1.visible = false rather then .dispose() fixes the problem, but why does this not happen to events for all the other controls when dispose() was being called?